# Using Ruby, how can I get the sum of a specific item out of an array of hashes?

Tags: ruby

I'm confused, I have `@quote.quote_line_items` and this is an array of items like this:

```
[{id: 85, part_number: "X67AC0M08", short_description: "X67 Threaded Caps M8, 50 pieces", list_price: "18.00", arg_cost: "12.15", long_description: "X67 Threaded Caps M8, 50 pieces", created_at: "2009-11-27 20:29:58", updated_at: "2009-11-27 20:29:58", quote_id: 1259353798}, {...}]
```

Consider if many items like this are in an array, how can I get, say, all of the `list_price` values summed up.

Is there a simple method to get the sum of all the `list_price` values by key?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given the `array = [itemA, ...]`, and each `item` has method `list_price`, then you can do that:

```
sum = array.map{|i|i.list_price}.reduce(:+)
```

or

```
sum = array.reduce(0) {|sum,item| sum + item.list_price }
```

If each item is hash, and you want to get values from `:list_price`, then try this:

```
sum = array.reduce(0) {|sum,item| sum + item[:list_price].to_f }
```

Note: edited after you corrected the example in question

Comment: You have a missing ampersand on the argument of the first reduce. Should be:

  sum = array.reduce(&:list_price)

Comment: @Douglas Actually it was all wrong, don't know where i get it from :-) I fixed it now